# How to use parental gate while using rev-mob add in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have implemented the SDK of parental gate one of my button.

1. But,I have not found anywhere how to use Parental control while **Rev-mob** and **Chart-boost** advertisements are running.
2. As both the ads are used in app-delegate file and I am unable control the flow when user clicks the add and I need to navigate them to another UI which contains the Parental controls view.
3. My app has been rejected for the same.  I want to know the proper way of setting the parental control over the adds of the app.

Please help me out. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your parental gate there

```
- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
```